# Prove $\sup(f^2(x))\le(\sup(f(x))^2$

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

Prove $\sup(f^2(x))\le(\sup(f(x))^2$

I am assuming this is true, I could find no counter examples.

$f(x)\le\sup(f(x))$

$f^2(x)\le(\sup(f(x)))^2$ when $f(x)\ge0$

$\sup(f^2(x))\le(\sup(f(x))^2$ when $f(x)\ge0$

now I can't figure out how to prove the case when $f(x)<0$. Any Ideas?

Comment: $x\leqslant y\implies x^2\leqslant y^2$ can be deduced if $x,y>0$. Look at the graph of $x\mapsto x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $f(x)=\ln(x)$ in $(0,1]$ with $$\infty=\sup\left(f^2(x)\right)\not\le\left(\sup f(x)\right)^2=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the opposite is true. $\sup(f)^2$ is the largest value of $f$ squared. This value will either be an infinity or $f(x)^2$ will have values arbitrarily close to $\sup(f)^2$. There also may be a negative value with larger absolute value than the supremum.

Answer (score 0):

Let $S = \{f(x)\}_x$, and let $S^2 = \{s^2\}_{s \in S}$.

Then $\sup S^2 = \max(\sup S, - \inf S)^2$.

Since $s^2 \le \sup S^2$, we have $(\sup S)^2 \le \sup S^2$ and $(\inf S)^2 \le \sup S^2$, so $\sup S^2 \ge \max(\sup S, - \inf S)^2$.

Since $|s| = \max(s, -s)$, we have $|s| \le \max(\sup S, -\inf S)$, and since
$x \mapsto x^2$ is increasing on $[0, \infty)$ we have
$s^2 = |s|^2 \le \max(\sup S, -\inf S)^2$. Taking the $\sup $ of the left hand side gives the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is any negative values function, then the right had side is $(\sup f)^2 = \inf |f|$ and the left had side is $\sup f^2 = (\sup |f|)^2$. Hence the inequality is false as soon as $f$ is not constant.